# Is there a way to track the number of bytes cleared by cache clearing code on Android 9+ devices?

Tags: android, caching, android-11

I use the following code snippet to clear the entire cache on devices running Android 9 and above. It works fine.

```
private void clearCache(){
    Intent intent = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        intent = new Intent(StorageManager.ACTION_CLEAR_APP_CACHE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
}
```

How can I know the number of bytes of cache that have been cleared?